# Zend google Calendar access not working anymore

Tags: zend-framework, calendar

I have used the Zend framework to access a google calendar for about 1 year. Today, all of a sudden the Zend command `getCalendarEventFeed()` throws an error:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 
Content-type: text/html; 
charset=UTF-8 
Date: Mon, 17 Nov 2014 20:43:36 GMT 
Expires: Mon, 17 Nov 2014 20:43:36 GMT 
Cache-control: private, max-age=0 
X-content-type-options: nosniff 
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN 
X-xss-protection: 1; 
mode=block Server: GSE 
Alternate-protocol: 443:quic,p=0.01 
Connection: close
```

Yesterday everything still worked, I did not change anything at all.

I use Zend framework 1.11.12, today I also tried the latest version 1.12.9, same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ditto here. Public calendar feed, so no authentication required, but suddenly nothing but 403.

Looks like Google deprecated the v2 calendar API today. See here: http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2014/06/calendar-gdata-api-google-calendar.html

Comment: Matt - What are you going to do? I was thinking rewriting the whole code with native Google API, but since I never used it before I hesitate to go that route. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I am rewriting for v3.  Fortunately, what I am doing is just pulling the next three events from a calendar feed.  Was pretty easy in the v2 API.  Unless they left out that functionality, I am hoping it won't be much worse in v3.