# Zend Gdata not working with google calendar API

Tags: zend-framework, google-calendar-api

My company is using zend gdata 1.11.7, relatively old, but they havent had the ability to move to newer things yet.  We have a program that adds events to a google calendar based on the forms submitted by the user.

This morning, we now get the error below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with
>   message 'Expected response code 200, got 403< HTML>< HEAD><
>   TITLE>Forbidden< /HEAD>< BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF"
>   TEXT="#000000">< H1>Forbidden< H2>Error 403< /BODY>< /HTML>
>   ' in
>   /homepages/26/d119734641/htdocs/app/ZendGdata-1.11.7/ZendGdata-1.11.7/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php:709

From everything I am reading, this is an authentication issue...but I have a problem, it was built so long ago that we do not have access to the google console for the API, what else could be the problem?  Did google stop supporting this way of authenticating that is used in this zend gdata?

Please help as currently I have everything happening manually from our online database to the calendar.

Comment: I am also getting an error using google calendar API to update calendar from website... everything was working fine couple days ago... Error: Expected response code 200, got 403 Forbidden Error 403 - I am using Zend 1.11.3

Comment: I have been getting this error as well, according to the deprecation document, they were only supporting up until April 2015. so maybe they shut it down.

Comment: You think this would be a pretty coming headache for people, is a write up anywhere or documentation how to update the code to bring it up to the right version

Comment: I too would welcome a simple guide to updating to v3

Answer (score 1):

Found this post
[Zend google Calendar access not working anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981668/zend-google-calendar-access-not-working-anymore)

Seems they discontinued it....

Back in November 2011, we announced the deprecation of the Calendar GData API (v1, v2) when the APIv3 was made available. We’ll now be shutting down these older versions on November 17, 2014.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/

seems to be the way to go. Still working on replacing my Zend_GData (Zend V1 project) with this but it seems promissing.

**EDIT**

I can confirm i was able to migrate all my zend_Gdata to google-api-php-client-master.

I can create event, update event, delete event, i work also with extendedProperties, all is fine. I've just one concern about the OAuth and the refreshToken, i hope that i understood how it work.

**/EDIT**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Zend anymore to list, add, delete events. You have to use google api v3. Here is an example of class you can use to manage events: [Authentification Zend Gdata (403 forbidden)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011264/authentification-zend-gdata-403-forbidden/27034888#27034888)