# Facing Error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Invalid code' in C:\xampp"

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am facing issue on using Google API for fetching Calendar Events.
The Error i am getting is :-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Invalid code' in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\Auth\OAuth2.php:88 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\Client.php(128): Google_Auth_OAuth2->authenticate('', false) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\googlecale.php(38): Google_Client->authenticate('') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\googlecale.php(71): getClient() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 88
```

After investigating i found my code is not executing after 
`$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);`
I am Pasting my code below :-

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', 'client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY)
));

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
  } else {

    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);

    print 'Enter verification code: ';

    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
    //var_dump('hi');exit;
    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $client->getAccessToken());
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 10,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => TRUE,
  'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
  print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
  print "Upcoming events:\n";
  foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
    $start = $event->start->dateTime;
    if (empty($start)) {
      $start = $event->start->date;
    }
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
  }
}
```

Please help me to get out of this thanks :)
below is my error screenshot :-
[image]

Comment: Please paste google client class here.

Comment: @sandeepsure i am not able to paste whole class over here. Can you please tell me what is the issue.

Comment: have you echo $accessToken? do you  get it properly?

Comment: @sandeepsure yes i tried ,my code is not ready to execute after that line even var_dump('hi'); is not comming after that line

Comment: can you provide the link from where you get this source?

Comment: @sandeepsure [go here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php)

Comment: have you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266663/uncaught-exception-google-auth-exception-with-message-invalid-code

Comment: i have already used that code and got successt.But i want to use Google official code.

Comment: Can you provide me the what exact difference between google code and the code provided in this link? i will provide you answer.

Comment: I got the exact same error. I just used code from google REST API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you have is that you can´t  enter the token, and you ran the code through the web server. You  must run the code from command line (http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php)

Look at this line:

```
$authCode = trim (fgets (STDIN));
```

The error said that the authorization code is invalid as $authCode is an empty string.